# Ignore FormBuilder property validator rule if another property is set to false

Tags: angular

When using **FormBuilder** in Angular 2-5, is it possible to ignore a validator rule if another property in the FormBuilder group was set to true/false?

Taking the following code example:

```
this._fb.group({
    "stake": [data.stake, Validators.compose([Validators.min(1), Validators.required])],
    "isSelected": data.isSelected
  });
```

If **isSelected** was set to true in the form, is there a way to ignore the validators in **stake**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you will have to use a combination of `setValidators`, `clearValidators` and `updateValueAndValidity` functions that come with the Angular [AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl).

Here is an example:

```
isSelected: boolean;
form: FormGroup;
setStakeValidators(): void {
    const stakeControl = this.form.get('stake');
    if (this.isSelected === false) {
        stakeControl.setValidators([Validators.min(1), Validators.required]);
    } else {
        stakeControl.clearValidators();
    }
    stakeControl.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

In this example function, you first get the `stake` control from the `FormGroup` you are working with. Then, based on the value of `isSelected`, you either set the validators to the ones you need, or clear them so no validation will occur. After, since the form will not automatically revalidate, you then run `updateValueAndValidity()` on the control to force a validation cycle.

You will notice in the documentation link I included above that there are asynchronous version of these functions available in case you are using asynchronous validators.

A way to watch for changes in the `isSelected` form control value is to subscribe to the `valueChanges` observable for that control, and run the validator changes to the `stake` control based on the value returned in the subscribe.

See below:

```
this.form.get('isSelected').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    const stakeControl = this.form.get('stake');
    if (value === false) {
        stakeControl.setValidators([Validators.min(1), Validators.required]);
    } else {
        stakeControl.clearValidators();
    }
    stakeControl.updateValueAndValidity();
})
```

UPDATE:

```
  this.betsForm = this.createFormGroup(this.betSlipItems);
  this.betsForm.get('isSelected').valueChanges.subscribe(value => { // console error here: TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of null
      const stakeControl = this.betsForm.get('stake');
      if (value === false) {
        stakeControl.setValidators([Validators.min(1), Validators.required]);
      } else {
        stakeControl.clearValidators();
      }
      stakeControl.updateValueAndValidity();
    });
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. How should I set setStakeValidators() to that isSelected in the form group? I this so far but its throwing an error (script.js) https://plnkr.co/edit/yoWX0gbBQ4i3tMdn0spV?p=info

Comment: That last part in my post is the best way to watch for changes in the `isSelected` field. It subscribes to the `valueChanges` observable for that control. Maybe, add that to your `buildArray` before the return statement. Then you can get rid of `setStakeValidators` function all together.

Comment: Thank you again - I added it again but still getting another error in here https://plnkr.co/edit/yoWX0gbBQ4i3tMdn0spV?p=info I should also have mentioned, that there could be several 'isSelected' in a form as the group is added dynamically - a bit like shopping cart items. Will that subscribe still work if there are multiple isSelected?

Comment: It would be a little easier to help you if you include **all** of your code in the plunk.

Comment: Okay, good. Trying moving that whole subscribe block of code under this line: `this.betsForm = this.createFormGroup(this.betSlipItems);`. I have added that to the answer, too. You just need to wait for `this.betsForm` to be initiated before trying to subscribe to something in it.

Comment: And, as far as subscribing to more than one `isSelected`: that should work, as long as you subscribe for each one. That could be tricky, but it should be doable. Each `isSelected` control may have to have a unique name in the form group in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to move the validation login to the `FormGroup` itself. After all this is an example of cross validation in which parts of the validation logic depend on multiple form elements.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, ValidatorFn, FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

const myValidator: ValidatorFn = (fg: FormGroup) => {
  const stake = fg.get('stake');
  const isSelected = fg.get('isSelected');

  if (isSelected.value) {
    return null;
  }

  const result = Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.min(5)])(stake);

  return !result || (!result.min && !result.required) ? null : { myError: true };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <form [formGroup]="form">
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isSelected" >Is Selected
    <input type="number" formControlName="stake" />
   </form>

   {{ form.valid }} 

  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      stake: [null],
      isSelected: [null]
    }, { validator: myValidator });
  }

}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhe6de)